# Java how to find out if a URL is http or https?

Tags: java, url, jsoup, web-crawler

I am writing a web crawler tool in Java. When I type the website name, how can I make it so that it connects to that site in http or https without me defining the protocol?

```
try {
   Jsoup.connect("google.com").get();
} catch (IOException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(LinkGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

But I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: google.com
```

What can I do? Are there any classes or libraries that do this?

What I'm trying to do is I have a list of 165 Courses, each with 65 - 71 html pages with links all throughout them. I am writing a Java program to test if the link is broken or not.

Comment: No, there is no such class in the JDK and I doubt any library allows that. You should be clear about what you want. HTTP and HTTPS are very different.

Comment: Just prefix `http://` or `https://` before the `URL`?

Comment: I don't know you usecase,  but try using http, it should be OK..  Most sites implement url redirection. I agree with the above comment though.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is I have a list of 165 Courses, each with 65 - 71 html pages with links all throughout them. I am writing a Java program to test if the link is broken or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own simple method to try both protocols, like:

```
static boolean usesHttps(final String urlWithoutProtocol) throws IOException {
    try {
        Jsoup.connect("http://" + urlWithoutProtocol).get();
        return false;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        Jsoup.connect("https://" + urlWithoutProtocol).get();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, your original code can be:

```
try {
    boolean shouldUseHttps = usesHttps("google.com");
} catch (final IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LinkGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Note: you should only use the usesHttps() method *once* per URL, to figure out which protocol to use. After you know that, you should connect using Jsoup.connect() directly. This will be more efficient.

Comment: I would not suggest such a method for every day use, since raising an exception is a costly operation. It is better to detect access mode once and a next time connect using protocol detected.